# Why can't I enable Ninja Ripper add-on?

Tags: add-on

When I try to enable the ninja ripper add-on, it gives me this error:

```
:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\BlenderFoundation.Blender_3.6.0.0_x64__ppwjx1n5r4v9t\Blender\3.6\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 333, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\vanes\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\import-ninja.py", line 7, in <module>
    from bpy_extras.io_utils import ImportHelper, orientation_helper_factory, axis_conversion, _check_axis_conversion
ImportError: cannot import name 'orientation_helper_factory' from 'bpy_extras.io_utils' (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\BlenderFoundation.Blender_3.6.0.0_x64__ppwjx1n5r4v9t\Blender\3.6\scripts\modules\bpy_extras\io_utils.py)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\BlenderFoundation.Blender_3.6.0.0_x64__ppwjx1n5r4v9t\Blender\3.6\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 333, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\vanes\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\import-ninja.py", line 7, in <module>
    from bpy_extras.io_utils import ImportHelper, orientation_helper_factory, axis_conversion, _check_axis_conversion
ImportError: cannot import name 'orientation_helper_factory' from 'bpy_extras.io_utils' (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\BlenderFoundation.Blender_3.6.0.0_x64__ppwjx1n5r4v9t\Blender\3.6\scripts\modules\bpy_extras\io_utils.py)
```

Comment: What add-on? Where do you get the add-on? How can we get it to test? [This one](https://github.com/kree-nickm/ninjaripper-blender-import) seems to register without errors.

Comment: +1 Martynas .... Anyway issues (errors) with enabling adding should go directly to an author of the addon. BTW If you open addon in text editor, at a beginning of the code is blender version that was written for ... so check that.

Comment: Hello and welcome. This is Q&A site run by volunteers, we are not programmers nor in any way associated with the Blender Foundation, decision making nor development process of the software. For bug reports with unknown third party addons please see [Where to Report a Bug](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports)